# vim (vimdiff) errors before opening every file with git difftool

Tags: vim, git

```
"~/Desktop/project/file.txt" [readonly] 81L, 2480C
Error detected while processing command line:
E344: Can't find directory "src/" in cdpath
E472: Command failed
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

^ This error pops up prior to opening every file. I have no idea from where the error is coming, because it says `... while processing command line:`, and then it's blank...

The command I'm using to invoke this is `git difftool`

Also, the directory I'm in when I call this is `~/Desktop/project/src`, which I assume is where it's getting the `Can't find directory "src/"`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar issue when using git difftool.  Check your `.vimrc` or plugins for `lcd %:p:h`.  I resolved the issue by adding the following when calling `lcd %:p:h`:

```
if !&diff
  lcd %:p:h
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Git is invoking `vimdiff` from the `~/Desktop/project` directory, and passes files as `src/...` With such a relative path, Vim will consult the `'cdpath'` setting, and whatever is in there doesn't have a `src/` directory, and so the error occurs (from the command-line).

The correct way for Git would be to use `./src/...`, or an absolute path, but that's probably difficult to change. Instead, you can influence Vim's default value via the `CDPATH` environment variable, or just put `:set cdpath=` in your `~/.vimrc` to pragmatically disable these lookups.